# jQuery ajax - get only user related result?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

A *logged on* user (session based)  has a grid of his last transactions :

```
policyNum | someInfo
--------------------------
    1000        ...
    2000        ...
    3000        ...
    5000        ...
```

When he clicks on a line ( *the first line for example ( total=1000)*) , he can see the ***details***.
(the result from server is json).

```
       items    | someInfo
    --------------------------
        100        ...
        300        ...            //100+300+600=1000
        600        ...
```

How I'm getting the data ?

I collect the  data (`policyNum` ) into js object and send it to the server via jQuery ajax.

**however** , the user can change the ajax request and seek for details for policies which he doesn't own.

I dont want to run the sql query and *then* to find out that he doesn't belong those fake number policies.

I want to stop it sooner.

How can I implement it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, you could encrypt the `policyNum` on the server. And from the JS, send to server the encrypted `policyNum`.
On the server you would easily decrypt it, and get the actual `policyNum`.